# In an AC Current, if the voltage is high, does this "amplify" the radiowave emissions without changing the frequency?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, voltage, electrical-engineering, antennas

**Hello**

My question comes from my interest in antennas i suppose:

I understand that antennas utilize alternating current to generate EMF Waves along a particular frequency depending on how quickly the AC current is alternating and changing between the two ends.

My question is more so to do with voltage, so that if the voltage flowing through the AC Circuit is higher, does this cause the Radiowave emissions to intensify hypothetically? Or to amplify for want of a better term?

Here I am thinking about Sound-waves to grasp this concept, because i understand that if i turn the volume up on my speaker, of course the sound-waves amplify, but yet they oscillate at the same frequency, the density of waves has increase, but the frequency or Hz depending on where i am in the song has remained the same. If the Hz increased, then the pitch of the song would change and i assuredly would not like that, i am here wondering if Voltage (as i understand it) works in the same way like increasing the volume on a speaker to amplify electromagnetic radiation.

Looking forward to a reply!

Comment: suggest you pose this question on the amateur radio stack exchange, there are lots of antenna & radiation experts there who can help you. -NN

Comment: If you want more signal going out, yes you put more power into the antenna. Just don't melt it...